# Is Hinduism the oldest among currently existent religions?

Tags: history, other-religions, christianity, islam, buddhism

Reading more and more mythological stories, I realize that the first religion on earth is **Hinduism**.([Source1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-oldest-surviving-religion-in-the-world-What-was-the-reason-it-has-survived-so-long))([Source2](http://www.wisegeek.org/which-are-the-oldest-religions-in-the-world.htm)) List of top religions:

1. **[Hinduism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism)** Oldest of all (Also known as [**Sanatana Dharma**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San%C4%81tan%C4%AB)
2. **[Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism)** also derived from ancient Sanskrit follower Buddha which sanskrit is the primary sacred language of Hinduism.
3. **[Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism)** came before Christianity.
4. **[Jainism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism)** also before Christianity (6th century B.C.)
5. **[Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity)** came in to existence in Kaliyuga according to Hinduism which explains about Yugas and [BCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era).
6. **[Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam)** came after Christianity.

Answer to the question in title will be helpful to all those who have doubt about oldest religion.

Comment: Hinduism came first, jainism came second(Rishabhdev, its founder and the 1st tirthankar, was also the avatar of Lord Vishnu). Buddhism came after Jainism because Lord Buddha was born much later. He was born around the time of Lord Mahavir, the 24th and last tirthankar of Jainism of the present cycle.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have missed Judaism, which came before Christianity. BTW, the name *Hindu* was given by Iranian Muslims. In that sense, it came even after Islam! :-) What probably you are referring is *Sanatan Dharma* and it might have first realized in present Indian subcontinent. But there is no authority of *Hinduism* over it, and that's why it's *Sanatan* / Eternal. Though we always discuss *Sanatan Dharma* on this site, we have named it as *Hinduism*, an oxymoron.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda My question is whether Hinduism is First and oldest Religion?

Comment: Just some clarifications: BCE stanads for _Before Common Era_, not "Christian Era" as you have quoted. BC commonly stands for _Before Christ_ which, it should be noted, it quite different than saying "Before Christian". According to Christianity, Christ's coming was fortold and expected long before his actual coming, so the date marker is in the middle of Christian history, not at the beginning. If you just want to count after Christ's coming that's up to your definition of Christianity, but it is not Christianity's definition and by any account you'd have to decide where Judaism fits.

Comment: Please note BCE is alternate to BC en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCE_%28disambiguation%29

Comment: As written (in any of the recent edits) this  would be better suited for [history.se]. As it is you're basically just presenting your theory using your own definitions and ... what ... looking for somebody to say "yes you're right"? That's not much of a question. Better to set your terms as far as what you mean by "still practiced" and just straight up ask what the oldest is. You're going to  find that it's harder to define "a religion" than you might think.

Comment: You have to correct yourself in respect of the first mentioned religion - Hinduism.  In ancient India, there was no religion in this land, that is known as India.  Religion should possess some qualities: 1) It should have a fixed deity , 2) A fixed holy text 3) Fixed rituals.  In ancient India, there was no religion, it was the way of Life called - Sanaatana Dharma.

Comment: This is truth that there was no religion in India. Then the Aryans(Hindus) came from Central Asia to India. They first settled in Punjab. Then Jainism had came after Hinduism. Then Buddhism had came after Jainism. Then Christianity had came after Buddhism. Then Islam and Sikh had came after Christianity.

Comment: Having no name for religion does not equate to "no religion". It's a misnomer to say there was no religion before Hinduism in India, just like how the Catholic church used to say the New World didn't have religion.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Where did you get your definition of religion? Time to look in a dictionary. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/religion

Answer (score 0):

Yes Hinduism is the oldest organized religion.

> 100th to 34th century BCE
>
> 9831 BCE
>       The Neolithic Revolution begins and results in a worldwide population explosion. The first cities, states, kingdoms, and organized religions begin to emerge. The early states were usually theocracies, in which the political power is justified by religious prestige. Beginning of First Sangam, Hinduism 'Shivan' period in South India.[citation needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_religion